# How to compare thousands of folders and files between two remote servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have two remote servers (windows), server A and server B.

server A has 500,000 folders with about 10-20 files inside each folder.

A process is in place that syncs these 500,000 folders and the files inside to server B, once a day @ 1am.

I need to verify that the sync is working. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) you can compare differences in files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is Powershell Script.
[Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/08/easily-compare-two-folders-by-using-powershell/) you can find more details, but this is the idea UNTEST so some type should be present:

Create a folder c:\compare on Server A and share it

After sync run: 
on server a

```
$fsoA = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path <path root folder> | export-csv -path c:\compare\fsoA.csv
```

on server b

```
$fsoB = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path <path root folder> | export-csv -path \\serverA\compare\fsoB.csv
```

on server a

```
fsoA = import-csv -path c:\compare\fsoA.csv
fsoB = import-csv -path c:\compare\fsoB.csv

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fsoA -DifferenceObject $fsoB
```